# Directly prove that $2x^2 -4x + 3 > 0$ for all real $x$

Tags: proof-writing

I'm asked (for homework which isn't graded but instead the basis of a quiz) to directly prove that $2x^2 -4x + 3 > 0$ for all real $x$.

I am VERY new to proofs.

The textbook's only example is a case that was simplified to `( foo )^2 + bar`, and it was assumed since `( foo )^2` is always positive that `( foo )^2` must be grater than or equal to `bar`.

I don't see a way to simplify this into `( something )^2 + something else`.

Comment: The technique is called [*completing the square*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square).

Comment: Do you remember the method of "completing the square" in order to solve quadratic equations? The idea of that is exactly what's needed here.

Comment: try to simplify it to : $ \text{ k(foo)^2 + bar } $

Comment: I didn't see this as a completing the square problem, totally caught me off guard, thanks guys!

Comment: You're not *that* new to proofs. There's no "hard line" between proofs and the exercices you've done all your mathematical life, the question "solve $5x+2=3$" is asking for a proof that a particular number solves that equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complete the square:

$$2x^2-4x+3=(\sqrt 2 x)^2-2\times(\sqrt2 x)\times\frac2{\sqrt2}+\left(\frac2{\sqrt2}\right)^2-\left(\frac2{\sqrt2}\right)^2+3\\=\left(\sqrt 2 x-\left(\frac2{\sqrt2}\right)\right)^2+1$$

Comment: $=\left(\sqrt 2 x\color{red}-\left(\frac2{\sqrt2}\right)\right)^2+1$

Answer (score 3):

$D = (-4)^2 - 4*3*2 < 0$, hence the polynomial $2x^2 - 4x + 3$ has no real roots, and so its graph does not intersect the horizontal axis. Thus, the value of this polynomial never change its sign, and, for, instance, when $x = 0$ it has the value $3 > 0$, so it always take positive values.

Answer (score 3):

This is a slight simplification of @Sami's solution:

$$2x^2-4x+3=2(x^2-2x+1)+1=2(x-1)^2+1>0$$